# mat-chip component is not recognized although I imported it

Tags: angular

I am facing an issue, `mat-chip` component is not recognized although I imported it.

> error NG8001: 'mat-chip' is not a known element:
> 1. If 'mat-chip' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

Here is an extract of my App module

```js
    ...............
    import { MatChipsModule } from '@angular/material/chips';
    ..............
    
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
    ...............
            MatChipsModule,
    .............
        ]
    ............
    })
```

### UPDATE

In fact it does not recognize all angular material component although I imported them

Comment: Not sure, since I didn’t do angular for a long time, but maybe you have to declare it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
npm install
```

in the project directory, which will solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following that works for me:

Ensure your mat chips NPM package is installed:

```
npm install @material/chips
```

Check the package is in your package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
      ...
    "@material/chips": "...",
      ...
},
```

Import into your app module:

```
import { MatChip } from '@angular/material';
```

Declare the component in your app module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
         ...
      MatChip
         ...
]
```

To use other Angular material components, you will need to install the NPM package for Angular material:

```
npm install angular/@material
```

Then import into your app.module and include in the NgModule imports and exports arrays.